# Is it possible to use strstr function to find the address and position of 1D array substring in a 2D array

Tags: c

I am trying to use strstr function to find the address and position of a substring which is a 1D array in a 2D array. The compiler does not give an error, but the program crashes, I was wondering why is it crashing and how to fix it.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int main()
 {
   char twodarray[][20]={"This is a","2D Array"};
   char onedarray[]={"Array"};
   char *pa;
   int position;

   pa=strstr(twodarray[20],onedarray);
   printf("%p",pa);
   position=(int)pa-(int)onedarray;
   printf("%d",position);

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's crashing because you are accessing memory way out bounds.

```
pa=strstr(twodarray[20],onedarray);
                   ^
                   |
                  here
```

`twodarray` stores only 2 arrays of dimension 20, `twodarray[20]` is trying to
access way beyond the maximum limit (`twodarray[1]`), that yields undefined
behaviour and the crash is a menifestation of that.

And to answer your question in the title: No, you cannot use `strstr` for
scanning a 2D as a 1D, because `strstr` expects a C-String, a continuous
sequence of characters that end with the `'\0'`-terminating byte. What you can
do is use `strstr` in a loop:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof twodarray / sizeof twodarray[0]; ++i)
{
    pa = strstr(twodarray[i], onedarray);
    ...
}
```

And the way you calculate the position is wrong, you have to calculate base on
the source, not the destination, because `strstr` returns a pointer to the source plus on offset:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof twodarray / sizeof twodarray[0]; ++i)
{
    size_t position;
    pa = strstr(twodarray[i], onedarray);

    if(pa == NULL)
        continue;

    position = pa - twodarray[i];

    printf("substring '%s' found at position %zu of '%s'\n", onedarray, position, twodarray[i]);
}
```

Comment: @AMD `twodarray[i]` (for any `i`) is a `char[20]`, when passed to `strstr` the `char[20]` decays into a `char*` and that's why you can pass it to `strstr` without having to use a cast.

Comment: Thank You, so if it was just twodarray (without the the index), would it decay into char*[20], instead of char*?

Comment: @AMD yes, and the compiler would warn you that you are passing incompatible types and if you execute it, it might crash because of that.